# How to use "wx_dpi_aware.manifest" of wxWidgets wxMSW with MinGW and CMake?

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets, manifest, dpi-aware

I'm using wxWidgets on Windows with MinGW64 toolchain and CMake. I am confused about how to make my program DPI-awared. When using Visual Studio, "wx_dpi_aware.manifest" can simply solve the problem; However, I do not know how to use it for MinGW64 and CMake.

I have asked ChatGPT and got these useless codes:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.res
    COMMAND windres.exe -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.res ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.rc
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.rc
    COMMENT "Generating resource file"
)

set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.res PROPERTIES
    OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.rc
)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/wx_dpi_aware.res)
```

And content of "wx_dpi_aware.rc" is:

```
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "C:/wx/3.2.2.1/include/wx/msw/wx_dpi_aware.manifest"
```

I know it is trying to add "wx_dpi_aware.res" as a source file, but cmake seems to ignore it (I have used "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" to see how it compiled, the result was that no "wx_dpi_aware.res" existed in the command).
Anyway, I want to make my program DPI-awared, otherwise the UI is blured under my 125% display.
**My environment:**
MinGW64 GCC 13.2.0 From winlibs
CMake 3.27.3
wxWidgets 3.2.2.1 Compiled by myself using CMake and GCC above

Comment: Have you tried adding your `.rc` file directly to the sources list?

Comment: @通配符, what is youe wxWidgets version and CMake version?

Comment: @AlexReinking Thank you. Now it can compile .rc file with the manifest. However, my program was still blured, the manifest seemed not to make a difference.